# RxJS Observable not triggering on change in Angular Material

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription

I am trying to perform an action as soon as the service i created is connected to his server. Currently im simply saving a `connected: boolean` which changes state on connection and connection lost, and return it as an observable.

With the subscribe i am only able to retrieve the initial state of the observable. The subscribe does **not** fire when the boolean changes its value (which it does).

Any help is appreciated.

**app.component.ts (subscription)**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.moduleService.isConnected().subscribe(value => console.log(value)); 
  }
```

**module.service.ts (injected in component)**

```
isConnected(): Observable<boolean> {
    return of(this._mqttApi.isConnected());
  }
```

**mqttApi.ts (boolean changes here)**

```
connected: boolean = false;

onConnect(){
  connected = true;
}

onConnectionLost(){
  connected = false
}

public isConnected(): boolean{
  return this.connected;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your module.service.ts you are only returning an observable that only emits once by using the `of`. What you need is a BehaviorSubject or Subject as the type for the connected property instead of a boolean inside your mqttApi.ts

And then make that observable public with connected.asObservable() if you don't want services using this observable to make changes to the subject. Otherwise you could also make the subject/behaviourSubject public.

And inside your methods you are calling connected.next(true|false)

Something like this:

```
connected: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

onConnect(){
  this.connected.next(true);
}

onConnectionLost(){
  this.connected.next(false)
}

public isConnected(): Observable<boolean>{
  return this.connected.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks. Could you please elaborate a little further why `of()` is not working? I used `of()` because it worked in the "tour of heroes" where they do more or less the same but with an array instead of a boolean.

Comment: Have a look at the offical documentation: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html. ```of``` emits the number of values given and then completes. Meaning if you only pass in one element it emits only that and then completes. If you pass an array of 3 elements, it would only emit those three and then completes. It's not an ongoing stream of data like you needed.